# Flutter TabBar wrong labelColor when use ThemeData

Tags: flutter, material-design, flutter-design, flutter-theme

I try to change labelColor value for TabBar via ThemeData.

```
child: MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(
            primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple,
          ).copyWith(
            secondary: Colors.amber,
          ),
          tabBarTheme: ThemeData.light().tabBarTheme.copyWith(
                labelColor: ThemeData.light().colorScheme.secondary,
              ),
        ),
        home: const RootContainer(),),);
```

So my tabs should have shade of amber color. Instead they are some blue ... (picture below).
What I'm doing wrong and how to fix it ?

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color doesn't change because the `ThemeData.light()` returns `ThemeData` that is not initilized.
For using the color of the theme, wrap your widget by `Builder` with `Theme.of(context)` like below.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(
          primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple,
        ).copyWith(
          secondary: Colors.amber,
        ),
      ),
      home: Builder(builder: (context) {
        final theme = Theme.of(context);
        
        return Theme(
          data: theme.copyWith(
            tabBarTheme: theme.tabBarTheme.copyWith(
              labelColor: theme.colorScheme.secondary,
            ),
          ),
          child: const RootContainer(),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works like a charm. Now I need to more deep dive with Builders.